# JQuery Template: How to preserve backslashes in content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

Using JQuery and the Microsoft Template plug-in, I have this in the template:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="Add('{{= path}}')" />
```

The path is a file system path of

```
C:\Photos\myPhoto.jpg
```

But the backslashes are interpreted as escape characters.  How could I format this to include the backslashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="Add('{{=encodeURIComponent(path)}}')" />
```

Though, a better approach would be to add a `click` handler after the template is created.

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  This requires at some point to reverse the hex encoded characters back.  Using the same thinking, is there some way to do this path.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")  I tried many a combination of different quantities of back slashes without getting the right one.

Comment: I marked it as answered because your method absolutely answers the question correctly.  I was able to add a decode in the Add method, which eventually worked out well.  The odd thing is that the path string already had double black slashes in it.  Given that, your method didn't care what it had, it just worked.